# count the selected range of cells after applying filter in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Thank you for reviewing my situation :) My attempts for just counting the selected rows in a particular column after applying a filter are pretty messed up. After applying filter, I am counting the selected rows for a column & it reports all rows. The filtered rows are 21 but it seems to be including all rows. I just want the selected rows count after filter.

```
Sub Report()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Testing")

    sh.Range("F21").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Fatal"

    ActiveSheet.Range("f21", ActiveSheet.Range("f21").End(xlDown)).Select

    MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    'FatCnt = Range("F21").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    'FatCnt = Selection.Count

    'MsgBox FatCnt    

    Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worksheet's native [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) does a nice job of counting filtered cells.

```
Sub Report()
    Dim k As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range(.Cells(21, "F"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Fatal"
            k = Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells) - 1 'minus 1 for the header
            Debug.Print k
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Damn you beat me to it :D

Comment: @Jeeped how did you arrive at Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells). what is 103 here? Thank you for the code, that helped :)

Comment: The reason I include links to the official documentation is so you can click them and find out.

Comment: After I got the count, I'd like to create a text box in a userform at a run time & show that value. What would be the property of text box that can hold this value? for eg :                                                                         Set txtB1 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtB1
            .Name = "chkDemo" & i
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 100
            .Left = 12
            .Top = 15 * i * 2
            
        End With``

Answer (score 3):

use the formula in cells to get the 'Fatal' count

```
=COUNTIF(F:F,"Fatal")
```

or

```
Sub Report()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing")
        fatalcount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F:F"), "Fatal")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ I was so engrossed in the VBA solution that I didn't think of it. This is much better than using VBA :)

Comment: I had kind of assumed that there was more than simply counting the *Fatal* cells in that report generation but good catch!